# Create Dummy Variables with Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dummy-variable

I'm trying to create a bunch of new Binary variables just for some columns that contain a certain word (and I want to name these new binary variables `BINARY_ +column name`), I'm trying to do it in this was way but it doesn't work:

```
# create empty list
List_of_dummy_names = [] 

# word
string = "WORD"

for col in list(df.columns.values):
    if string in df.columns.values[col]:
        List_of_dummy_names.append('BINARY_'+col)
```

Comment: Do you have only one row? Or you want to check if a word exist in entire column or you want to check individual cell and append that column to the list.

Comment: `List_of_dummy_names = ['BINARY_' + col for col in df.columns.astype(str) if string in col]`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `col` looks like some kind of a collection. You probably want to do this:

```
List_of_dummy_names.append('BINARY_'+string)
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I tried but I'm getting this error:

Comment: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rename pandas dataframe column with the new created List_of_dummy_names (elements with 'BINARY_'+column_name) then you can follow my answer.

lets say

```
cv = list(df.columns.values)
#cv = ['aword', 'bword', 'c']
search_String = 'word'
replace_dict = dict(zip(cv,['BINARY_'+x if search_String in x else x for x in cv]))
#{'aword': 'BINARY_aword', 'bword': 'BINARY_bword', 'c': 'c'}
#Then in pandas dataframe rename method, use this dictinary
new_df = df.rename(col=replace_dict)
```

Also check if you could use the below

```
List_of_dummy_names = ['BINARY_'+x for x in cv if search_String in x ]
#['BINARY_aword', 'BINARY_bword']  #filters the element having 'word' in them and prefixed with 'BINARY_'
```

Check if you need this (Cause i am confused about 'what you are looking for')

```
#df has only one column named 'col_to_replace'
col_to_replace
   aword
   bword
   c
df['col_to_replace'] = ['BINARY_'+x if search_String in x else x for x in df['col_to_replace']]
#col_to_replace
   BINARY_aword  #prefixed
   BINARY_bword  #prefixed
   c             #word not found, so as it was
```

Now you got your new list of column names in a list.

```
List_of_dummy_names #['BINARY_aword', 'BINARY_bword']
#loop over it and create new columns in existing dataframe
for col_Name in List_of_dummy_names:
    df[col_Name] = 'default_value_1' #it will create new column "BINARY_aword" and all the row_values as string 'default_value_1' for first loop and in 2nd loop new column "BINARY_aword" with all values as 'default_value_1'.
```

if you already have a values in a list with len(list) == len(df) then assign that list as df[col_Name] = list_of_values_having_same_length_as_DF

Comment: Hi! thanks for your suggestion, but I'm trying to add these new binary variables to the dataframe

Comment: @JamesPietroZanzarelli- then use  List_of_dummy_names  = ['BINARY_'+x  for x in cv if search_String in x] then use this list  as values, else use the above dictionary and call a "map" function over a dataframe column to replace values.

Comment: This is really slow. If you're working with pandas, these aren't the types of commands you should be giving.

Comment: yup, I know. but tried to help, i have also suggested OP to use a map.

Comment: now I have this List_of_dummy_names, is it possible to attached these as additional columns to an existing data frame? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Great. in that case,  under columns what values do you want to put in??if any default value, then check the edit.